# Issues with wildcard (*) in Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I am trying to symbolically link multiple files using my Makefile using the command: `ln -s $(PWD)/bin/* ../../../bin/destination`

If I run the command in native bash it works fine, but run in the Makefile it simply creates an * in the destination directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does the `*` link point to when this happens? What shell is make using for recipes? Is this in a recipe or in some other make context?

Comment: Show your `Makefile`  please.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `$(wildcard $(PWD)/bin/*)` instead of `$(PWD)/bin/*` (assuming you are using GNU make; read it about [wildcard pitfalls](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Pitfall.html#Wildcard-Pitfall)) and about the [wildcard function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html)

To debug the issue, I would suggest using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (as `remake -x`) and/or `make --trace`

Comment: Thanks for the the suggestion! Unfortunately it is still not working.